# Banking Code assignment, calling methods within a class

Tags: python, class, methods

Being relatively new to coding, some of the small issues I have not yet learn to tweak out. In this code my goal is to print the account's name, plus their balance based off of a withdraw, deposit, or simply checking. The name and values will print, however, they are not in a line, as well as "none" prints at the end, and i cannot seem to rid it. I need suggestions on how to fix. I believe the problem stems somewhere within the methods and calling them but am not sure.

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self, name, balance):
    self.name = name
    self.balance = balance
  def Withdraw(self):
    if Amount1 > self.balance:
     self.withdraw = "You have exceeded your balance."
     print (self.withdraw)
    elif Amount1 < self.balance:
     self.withdraw = (self.balance - Amount1)
     print (self.withdraw)
  def Deposit(self):
     self.deposit = (self.balance + Amount2)
     print (self.deposit)
  def CheckBalance(self):
     self.check = self.balance
     print (self.check)


account1 = Account("Barbara", 500.00)   
account2 = Account("Joe", 150.00)
account3 = Account("Frank", 20.00)

Action = input("What would you like to do; check balance(c), deposit(d), or withdraw(w)? ")
if Action == "w": 
  Amount1 = int(input("What amount would you like to withraw?"))
  print (account1.name + str(account1.Withdraw()))
  print (account2.name + str(account2.Withdraw()))
  print (account3.name + str(account3.Withdraw()))
if Action == "d":
  Amount2 = int(input("What amount would you like to deposit? "))
  print (account1.name + str(account1.Deposit()))
  print (account2.name + str(account2.Deposit()))
  print (account3.name + str(account3.Deposit()))
if Action == "c":
  print (account1.name + str(account1.CheckBalance()))
  print (account2.name + str(account2.CheckBalance()))
  print (account3.name + str(account3.CheckBalance()))


This is the code i have running so far
```

Comment: 1)If your function/method doesn't have a `return` then is returns `None` by default 2) you should be updating `self.balance` (like `self.balance=self.balance+...` ) with your withdraw and deposit methods, and then returning `self.balance` in your `CheckBalance` method. Otherwise you're not actually changing the account balance 3) withdraw and deposit should take `amount` as in input parameter to update the balance, not rely on trying to make sure the variables magically have the same name

Comment: Also worth noting, per PEP8 guidelines, your methods and variables should use snake_case not CamelCase, e.g., `Action ` should be `action`, `Deposit`->`deposit`, `CheckBalance`->`check_balance`